# como fazer quando uma pergunta sobre programação tambem envolve um contexto fora de foco?

Tags: debate, suporte

Hoje estava com uma dúvida sobre escolher entre utilizar WiFi ou Bluetooth, 
estava mais preocupado com a parte de programação das interfaces, porem eu não podia ignorar o fato que eu faria a programação embarcada do outro lado, nem como as características técnicas dos módulos a serem utilizado, como fazer esse tipo de pergunta?
e ela é aceita no site?

Comment: A resposta é "depende". Depende de muita coisa... Se seguir as [regras do site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) claro que é aceite.

Answer (score 7):

O maior problema com seu raciocínio é tentar resolver tudo de uma só vez. Por isso acaba ficando muito amplo.

Seja para perguntar aqui no SOpt ou para desenvolver uma solução na vida real, é melhor dividir o problema em partes menores e encontrar as soluções parciais para cada uma delas.

Eu entendo que é necessário ter uma visão geral, mas não espere que uma abstração resolva todos os detalhes e questões.

Enfim, faça uma pergunta sobre um ponto específico, contextualizando o problema, mas abstraindo as demais dúvidas num primeiro momento. Depois de obter uma resposta, vá para o próximo tópico.

Lembrando que existe a possibilidade de não surgir uma resposta satisfatória, seja por falta de usuários que conhecem o assunto ou porque lhes falta disponibilidade.

Comment: O 1º e último paragrafos são na mosca, tinham que ir pralgum FAQ.